# Is it possible to add an ActionListener in choice in GUI?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist

```
list.addActionListener(this);
```

I got an error of cannot find symbol though I used it in `JButton` and was accepted.

Comment: What symbol is it that cannot be found? Of what type is list?

Comment: this question isn't answerable in this form,

Comment: @BenvanGompel the method addActionListener(); can't be found

Answer (score 2):

Look through the [methods of `JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#method_summary) in the docs.  (that's what they are for).  The docs. will tell you exactly what type(s) of listeners can be added to a component.

Be sure to also check the methods of the super classes (which are inherited by the class).  Scroll further down to see them.

Comment: +1 I think that ***, please choice isn't JComboBox in AWT, then ItemListener or ActionListener